# How to add cutom header in Http.outboundGateway in Spring Integration Rest Service Call?

Tags: spring-integration, custom-headers, header-enricher

I am trying to make Rest Web-service POST method call with custom header . Tried to add the custom header in enrichHeaders still getting HTTP 403 Forbidden response. Could you please help with right code snippet?

```
.enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("X-API-Key","ABCEDABCED").header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).header(APP_NAME, XXX).header(ACCEPT,
                        APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway(config.getXxxWebServiceUrl()).httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                        .expectedResponseType(String.class).requestFactory(xxxRequestFactory()),
                        c -> c.advice(sendToArchive.sendToArhive()))
                .log().get();
```

**Error Logs :-**

```
[bean 'xxxDispatcher1.http:outbound-gateway#0' for component 'xxxDispatcher1.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2'; defined in: 'class path resource [service/xxxDispatcher.class]'; from source: 'bean method xxxDispatcher1']; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: [{"message":"Forbidden"}]
    at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Header mappings section in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/http.html#http-header-mapping

> By default, all standard HTTP headers are mapped from the message to HTTP request or response headers without further configuration.

So, since you don't provide a `mappedRequestHeaders()` option for the `Http.outboundGateway()` therefore your `APP_NAME` custom header is not mapped and not transferred over the HTTP to the REST service.

Comment: Awesome mate, that worked. Thanks for prompt solution.